# Vega-lite to show text values in SI units

Tags: vega-lite

My sample source code is following

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28000}, {"a": "B", "b": 55000}, 
      {"a": "C", "b": 43000}, {"a": "D", "b": 91000}, 
      {"a": "E", "b": 81000}, {"a": "F", "b": 53000},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19000}, {"a": "H", "b": 87000}, 
      {"a": "I", "b": 52000}
    ]
  },
    "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
  },
  {
    "mark":{
       "type":"text",
       "align":"center",
       "baseline":"middle",
       "dx":0,
       "dy":-5
    } ,
    "encoding":{
       "text":{"field":"b","type":"quantitative"}
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I want the text marks to be dynamically displayed in SI units. So in my example, `28k`, `55k`, `43k` so an so forth.

How can I do that in Vega-lite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add formatter in your text as done below or in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAEwAHAAMuQC+ColoIABCqWhiYrnZBUXoAMLlqAAsAMzVtSBJACJNAJwAjB2FXcUAok2ZQ-kjSQBiTWLtM3UgAOJNA33DqwASkwDsHQC6BSBwslBsyjSyZGigAB4PIABmNHCCysUoSpgAnjg4MVZGwELcosEkI8aBAXoIkJ5BPo7hY0DUzv8Xu9Pt90Gk-oDgegAI4MJCyHSBHSkEB5M4I-5wdTxUDIdQAa2K1hZnXZXPCIABQOKmDgj0wUOEZD0ICgFzFLKU1ggn1uxJA4O8aKUymeqGyuqxqH4YjOFyuNzuLzFEuxHy+3OCwo1ZIpVICNFpSlebHUyEl6Eo6Th9LypyAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28000},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55000},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43000},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91000},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81000},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53000},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19000},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87000}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2s"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Edits**

To provide different formats on different value ranges you can simply perform `calculate` transform and create the formatted values based on conditions. Then, simply use the value field as your `text` as done below or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAEwAHAAMuQC+ColoIABCqWhiYrnZBUXoAMLlqAAsAMzVtSBJACJNAJwAjB2FXcUAok2ZQ-kjSQBiTWLtM3UgAOJNA33DqwASkwDsO6PoAJKL6a2tfX15ALoFIJjqSLIQAGZs6gjxoFBRUAYggCcGK-kwDAQlCYhgAfIYbojDAB+Qyfb4BAAU4Mh0IUAHJKK0IPiAJSGVBor7ITDYgK4pgEyjpEmk4JICDFTBwAAemAAalEYiB7ko4LIoGxlDRZGQ0KAefKQO8aHBBMpiiglJgAJ44UHoWRsBAyqLsnk0TnhEDAzyCfSyixoGqPHVKlVqjXoNLavUGkAARwYrx0gR0pBFj2BOrg6l+IGQ6gA1sVrHHOomU9bdfqubzMOzhGQ9CAoOLuXGlNYIGqZf6Td4nUplIrUNlm27UPwxI9xZLpbKldy+e7Veq83zBdFQXlZw8gA).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28000},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55000},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43000},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91000},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81000},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53000},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19000},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87000},
      {"a": "I", "b": 523399}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datum.b > 99999 ? format(datum.b,'.3s') : format(datum.b,'.2s')",
      "as": "textValue"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": -5
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "textValue"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

You can refer the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#d3-format) to know more about number format or check the [tests](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/main/test/format-type-s-test.js) file on github

Comment: Thanks for this. From your code, I want the last text mark to be displayed as `523k` but it currently shows as `520k`. Also, if I change that to `523999`, the text to be displayed should be `524k`, but it still shows `520k`.

Comment: For the `523200` value you can provide `.3s` in format  which will give `523k` but the other values will get a decimal value. Also the 523299 will not be 524 instead if its 523**599** then you will get `524k` but for that you need to add `.3s`. The other variation for this is to use a transform calculate in which transform the values before by using ternary conditions. Updating the answer with transform example.

Comment: I have a follow up question regarding conditional formatting of text mark [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808216/how-to-use-conditional-statements-in-vega-lite-transform).