# How to use conditional statements in Vega-lite transform

Tags: vega-lite

My sample source code is following

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 302},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2794},
      {"a": "C", "b": 96237},
      {"a": "D", "b": 766995},
      {"a": "E", "b": 7691230},
      {"a": "F", "b": 59755899},
      {"a": "G", "b": 229910863},
      {"a": "H", "b": 9342989068},
      {"a": "I", "b": 19617657788},
      {"a": "J", "b": 140800000001}
    ]
  },
    "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
  },
  {
    "mark":{
       "type":"text",
       "align":"center",
       "baseline":"middle",
       "dx":0,
       "dy":-5
    } ,
    "encoding":{
       "text":{"field":"b","type":"quantitative"}
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I want Vega-lite to generate labels for text mark by following logic

```
if absoluteValue(b)>1 and if absoluteValue(b)<999 then format""
else
if absoluteValue(b)>1000 and if absoluteValue(b)<9999 then format.2s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>10000 and if absoluteValue(b)<99999 then format.3s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>100000 and if absoluteValue(b)<999999 then format.4s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>1000000 and if absoluteValue(b)<9999999 then format.2s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>10000000 and if absoluteValue(b)<99999999 then format.3s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>100000000 and if absoluteValue(b)<999999999 then format.4s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>1000000000 and if absoluteValue(b)<9999999999 then format.2s
else
if absoluteValue(b)>10000000000 and if absoluteValue(b)<99999999999 then format.3s
else
format.4s
```

Following is my desired result

```
| a     | b             | desired format    |
|---    |-------------- |----------------   |
| A     | 302           | 302               |
| B     | 2794          | 2.8k              |
| C     | 96237         | 96.2k             |
| D     | 766995        | 767.0k            |
| E     | 7691230       | 7.7M              |
| F     | 59755899      | 59.8M             |
| G     | 229910863     | 229.9M            |
| H     | 9342989068    | 9.3G              |
| I     | 19617657788   | 19.6G             |
|       | 140800000001  | 140.8G            |
```

Wahab Memon showed me in a different question [Vega-lite to show text values in SI units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804178/vega-lite-to-show-text-values-in-si-units) how to use the conditional statements, but I don't know how to expand that to multiple statements. I also, can't find any documentation that demonstrates it. I was wondering if I can use `if` or `switch` statements to achieve this.

Can someone please point me to the correct direction. Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the possible ways to define your conditions using ternary in calculate which works same as if-else:

```
"transform": [
    {
      "calculate": " 0 < datum.b && datum.b < 999 ? format(datum.b,'.1s') : 999 < datum.b && datum.b < 9999? format(datum.b,'.2s') : 9999 < datum.b && datum.b < 9999? format(datum.b,'.3s') : format(datum.b,'.4s')",
      "as": "textValue"
    }
  ],
```

Another cleaner option is use multiple calculate:

```
"transform": [
        {
          "calculate": " 0 < datum.b && datum.b < < 999 ? format(datum.b,'.1s') : datum.textValue",
          "as": "textValue"
        }, {
          "calculate": "999 < datum.b && datum.b < < 9999? format(datum.b,'.2s') : datum.textValue",
          "as": "textValue"
        }, {
          "calculate": "9999 < datum.b && datum.b < < 9999? format(datum.b,'.3s') : datum.textValue",
          "as": "textValue"
        }
      ],
```

**Edit**

Refer the below snippet and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAMwADABMAL4KiWggAEKpaNkA7ACcACz5hegAwmWoVQBs2ekV9SBJACItFW1tVVViPUkAooMjAIydmRNFAGItYlUVYmIAHKNL6ADiLdnZo7OZ223p+yAAEi1V6TWnu5lt2zcAki2z7bNDYgqFW2HwKvSKACkfjULpk4fDMrNcgBdfIgTDqJCyCAAMzY6gQ8VAUCiUAYggCcCKhkyhgAPH4AgwEJQmIYAGTsxmYZms+kAXkMoyqhgA-IY8QSAgAKfw8llMBQAciVAEpDKhuby0kokBAipg4AAPTAANSiIB6JMEZIphqK5zhAq1Co5XLl2udwqq4slyEwsqZCuVlGyEDVGpdlENJvNgmCeoNxrNFqtpPJlIdCOdHtdnKjbLpgu9Pol+P9gflrJD6XD6s1uejybjCf16BjKfjaZtGft6Ed8JzQb5+cbheLJd95ZlY5DNTrkcbHZburb6ObqbB1ttmf7CKdDLHboLXpLpb9M+HiqVoYXDeHy4tq6Tsc3xPTdqpe-3tMPV+PR5FkKZ7ntOAazjetYRveVaPvGz7thuXZbh+u4gAO+70ieo7-kBIGjFOUrgVec53lGcGti+naWihPaflmP4Hth7q4RO+GERWEG3tB5FIZRiGvsh750WhGE-lhR44VW47AfhoFEZW2o1mRS58Qh66CTRwk7n26GMdmf7SQBrGyXJHGXtJpE8apmnqRRKJKHAshQGwyg0LIZBoKARpeSAOI0HAgjKEUKBKJgACeOBfiAshsAg7lPr0Ro0G2oAUp4gj6B5FhoIsaLhb5-mBcF6A6uikXRQAjgwWI6IEOikJaaIUuFcDqESIDIOoADWvkRVFRTWO1YVsGwgg6DgaAYjEuQ9F1vXhOVA0CZgCbCGQeggFATmGsNIDWBAgXudF8XeDlSjKD5qCZBdBWoPwYgjWNE1TeoM2Oc5rnuZ5i0doVAVBVRLazSiuRAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 302},
      {"a": "B", "b": 2794},
      {"a": "C", "b": 96237},
      {"a": "D", "b": 766995},
      {"a": "E", "b": 7691230},
      {"a": "F", "b": 59755899},
      {"a": "G", "b": 229910863},
      {"a": "H", "b": 9342989068},
      {"a": "I", "b": 19617657788},
      {"a": "J", "b": 140800000001}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": " 0 < datum.b && datum.b <= 999 ? format(datum.b,'') : datum.b",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "1000 <= datum.b && datum.b <= 9999? format(datum.b,'.2s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "10000 <= datum.b && datum.b <= 99999? format(datum.b,'.3s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "100000 <= datum.b && datum.b <= 999999? format(datum.b,'.4s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "1000000 < datum.b && datum.b <= 9999999? format(datum.b,'.2s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "10000000 < datum.b && datum.b <= 99999999? format(datum.b,'.3s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "100000000 < datum.b && datum.b <= 999999999? format(datum.b,'.4s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "1000000000 < datum.b && datum.b <= 9999999999? format(datum.b,'.2s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "10000000000 < datum.b && datum.b <= 99999999999? format(datum.b,'.3s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "100000000000 < datum.b && datum.b <= 999999999999? format(datum.b,'.4s') : datum.textVal",
      "as": "textVal"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true}},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": -5,
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "textVal"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with working code snippet and also made edit to the ternary syntax. I missed the `&&` part and thought that it will work as is. Try the above and let me know if it works